# Дано натуральное число п. Обчислить : 1^1 - 2^1+3^2 - 4^2+5^3 - 6^3… ±п^k

Tags: javascript

Добился изменяющегося знака, но степени пока не могу

```
<script>
let n = 10
function xsum(n)
{
    let b = 0
    for (let a = 1; a <= n; a++)
    {
        if (a % 2 != 0)
        {
            b += a
        }
        else 
        {
            b -= a
        }
    }
    return b
}
</script>
```

Comment: Возведение числа в степень две звездочки ** (4 ** 2 = 16)

Comment: Обчислить? Это что за тётко-бухгалтерский язык?

Comment: Всмысле, обчислить до 10*

Comment: вопрос к задаче поставлен некорректно. Понятно, что последовательность, но какой формулой она задаеться не понятно. При чём тут Pi ?

Comment: Нет слова "обчислить". Что оно означает?

Comment: @Эникейщик Это на украинском

Comment: @nomnoms12 разве не как-нибудь вроде "обчисливати" должно быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы изменялся знак `+` на `-` можно использовать тернарный оператор `?`

```
i % 2 ? 1 : -1 // будет чередовать 1 и -1 каждую итерацию
```

Чтобы получить нужное `k` каждую итерацию, то можно воспользоваться [побитовым оператором](https://learn.javascript.ru/bitwise-operators) правого сдвига `>>`.

```
k(i) = (i + 1) >> 1 // будет прибавлять 1 к своему значению через каждые 2 итерации
```

Чтобы возвеси `n` в степень `k` используйте `Math.pow(n, k)` или `n**k`.

```
n^k = (i**((i + 1) >> 1)
```

В итоге задачу можно решить примерно так:

```js
function xsum(n) {
  let result = 1;
  if (n <= 1) return result;
  for (let i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
      result += (i % 2 ? 1 : -1) * (i**((i + 1) >> 1));
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(xsum(1), xsum(2), xsum(3), xsum(4), xsum(5)) // 1, -1, 8, -8, 117
```